# How to pair update records in log table using trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I wrote a trigger after update that has two inserts (on from table INSERTED and one from table DELETED). It is working really well, but i have a problem, when i try to identify pair of records -> after and before UPDATE. Every time i will update record it will add 2 rows in my log table, but i am not able to identify pair of them -> which two where from that update action (i have column that can keep unique number for that pair).

Is it possible to do it? To pair that Updated record History (which is in two rows after trigger) to have same uniqe index?

here is my sample code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Logging trigger]

ON [dbo].[tbl_Persons]

AFTER UPDATE, DELETE

AS

  INSERT tbl_Persons_LOG ([Login],
  [ID],
  [Title])

    SELECT (SELECT
             SYSTEM_USER),
           [ID],
           [TITLE]
    FROM DELETED


  INSERT tbl_Persons_LOG ([Login],
  [ID],
  [Title])

    SELECT (SELECT
             SYSTEM_USER),
           [ID],
           [TITLE]
    FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Many dbms products do not follow the ANSI SQL Standard.)

Comment: SQL EXPRESS and i am using Management Studio for this.